How to get the documentation for all the methods in the smart contract when using solc --devdoc
I am running the following command to generate Developer Documentation for a smart contract in JSON format:
solc --devdoc Contract.sol > doc.json
The problem I am having is that some of the methods that the contract has seem to be excluded from the output.
Why does this happen? Is there a way to list all of the methods in the documentation produced?
